# Good STL-like library for C

Tags: c, architecture, data-structures

What are good libraries for C with datastructures like vectors, deques, stacks, hashmaps, treemaps, sets, etc.? Plain C, please, and platform-independent.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [Glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/) library used on the Gnome project may also be some use. Moreover it is pretty well tested.

IBM developer works has a good tutorial on its use: [Manage C data using the GLib collections](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/)

Comment: But see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17448240/1593077): It seems glib assumes you never go out of memory, and if you do, it `abort()`s your program, which is a pretty rough constraint.

Comment: I tried it before, harder to use than stl(cumber some) and have no performance benefits compare to stl.

Answer (score 14):

As always, Google is your friend:

http://nixbit.com/cat/programming/libraries/c-generic-library/

specifically:

http://nixbit.com/cat/programming/libraries/generic-data-structures-library/

Answer (score 5):

There's some stuff in the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) (APR) that I'd expect to be very solid.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe http://sglib.sourceforge.net/ if you want an easy to use, very fast, macro based library.

Answer (score 2):

If hash tables, extensible strings and dynamic vector are enough for your needs, please have a look at the library I put toghether: http://code.google.com/p/c-libutl/.

I also would welcome any feedback!