# Need a general purpose library, pure C

Tags: c, data-structures

Could you recommend a good general purpose data container library for C (pure C, not C++)?
I just need basic structures, like dynamic arrays, hash tables, etc.

(Note: By "good" I mean fast + elegant interface).

Comment: I realize it is a (quite) duplicated question : First line in SO searching tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540/good-stl-like-library-for-c , and there is quite more, just searching for " [c] glib library"

Comment: Zifre - no, it's not a solution (for me). I've been progrmaming C++ for almost 20 years, so I don't think I need any advice on available C++ libs. Here I was interested what's happening in pure C land. 

And I'm very satisfied with the answers, thanks everyone! Especially that "C interfaces and implementations" - it looks like a gem.

Comment: at this point I'am just wondering why the C std comitee never provided a standardisations for a common and widely used library. Glib is quite used AFAIK? C++ commitee bring the STL in the standard for instance ... Well , is it a good question for SO ? :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/) qualifies as both fast and elegant.   It includes many different kinds of containers, some string processing, multiprecision arithmetic, exceptions, a couple of different memory managers.  Nice stuff.

There's a book, but you don't need to buy it to use the software.

Answer (score 15):

Isn't Glib sufficient for your needs ? :-)
[developer.gnome.org/glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib)

Comment: This link is outdated. Here is an update: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/

Comment: @Jamer thnx. I update the post with out link.

Answer (score 14):

Apache Portable Runtime

http://apr.apache.org/

Includes modules for these areas.

- Platform Definitions
- Internal Memory Allocation
- Atomic Operations
- Dynamic Object Handling
- Functions for manipulating the environment
- Error Codes
- File Information
- File I/O Handling Functions
- Filename Matching Functions
- Miscellaneous library routines
- Command Argument Parsing
- Global Locking Routines
- Hash Tables
- General Purpose Library Routines
- MMAP (Memory Map) Routines
- Network Routines
- Poll Routines
- Memory Pool Functions
- Portability Routines
- Process Locking Routines
- Random Functions
- Ring Macro Implementations
- Shared Memory Routines
- Signal Handling
- String routines
- Internal APR support functions
- Table and Array Functions
- Condition Variable Routines
- Thread Mutex Routines
- Threads and Process Functions
- Reader/Writer Lock Routines
- Time Routines
- User and Group ID Services

Answer (score 7):

I previously recommended [MemSL](http://www.memorystructures.com/), but the website and company seem to have gone extinct. I would now suggest [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/), it covers much of the same functionality and is widely supported and used throughout the Linux community.

I used MemSL when implementing an x86 kernel, and I found it to be general, reliable, and bug free.

From the description:
C Overview of the Memory Structures Library (MemSL)

The Memory Structures Library, MemSL for short, is a library of useful routines allowing the efficient use of complex data structures in C. The MemSL contains routines for managing:

- Multi-Dimensional Dynamically Allocated Arrays
- Single Linked Lists
- Double Linked Lists
- Circular Linked Lists
- Cut, Copy and Paste with Linked Lists
- Multiple Positional Pointers to Linked Lists
- Stacks
- Queues
- Dequeues
- Sets
- Bags
- Tables
- Dictionaries
- Hash Tables with Separate Chaining
- Hash Tables with User-Defined Paging
- Hash Tables with Dynamic Paging
- Binary Search Trees
- Threaded Binary Search Trees
- AVL Balanced Binary Search Trees
- AVL Balanced Threaded Binary Search Trees
- Priority Heaps
- Fully Dynamic Priority Search Queues

Comment: The MemSL link does not work (at the moment, 2012-06-08). This link seems to have the MemSL nowadays: http://www.memorystructures.com/. The download link goes to http://sourceforge.net/projects/memsl2/(with last update 2009-11-12).

Comment: I updated the link, it should work again.

Comment: looks like MemSL is dead. I updated my reply to make note of that and added a link to glib, which is probably a better alternative anyway since it has wide support.

Answer (score 5):

You might also want to check out the [iMatix SFL](http://legacy.imatix.com/html/sfl/), to quote their webpage:

> The SFL (Standard Function Library) from iMatix is a portable function
> library for C/C++ programs. The SFL is the result of many years' development,
> and is provided as Open Source software for the benefit of the
> Internet community.
> The SFL is written in ANSI C and has been ported to MS-DOS, Windows, OS/2, Linux
> and other UNIX systems (IBM AIX, SunOS, HP/UX, Solaris, NetBSD, FreeBSD,
> SCO OpenServer,> Digital UNIX) and Digital OpenVMS. It comes with complete sources and
> documentation in HTML.
>
> The SFL provides about 450 functions that cover these areas:
>
> - Compression, encryption, and encoding;
> - Datatype conversion and formatting;
> - Dates, times, and calendars;
> - Directory and environment access;
> - User and process groups;
> - Inverted bitmap indices;
> - Symbol tables;
> - Error message files;
> - Configuration files;
> - String manipulation and searching;
> - File access;
> - Internet socket access;
> - Internet programming (MIME, CGI);
> - SMTP (e-mail) access;
> - Server (batch) programming;
> - Program tracing.
>
> The SFL is free software that you may use and distribute for private or commercial
> purposes according to the [SFL License Agreement](http://legacy.imatix.com/html/sfl/sfl4.htm#license).

More details about the API itself, see [here](http://legacy.imatix.com/html/sfl/index.htm).

Answer (score 4):

[Sglib](http://freshmeat.net/projects/sglib/) "is a generic library for C that was inspired by the Standard Template Library from C++"

Answer (score 2):

Let me add:

http://libslack.org

(... and add to this: libcx)

Answer (score 2):

You may interested in looking at qLibc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qlibc
http://www.qdecoder.org/qlibc/

It's a general purpose complete C/C++ library which includes all kinds of containers and general library routines.