# General purpose library for standard C?

Tags: c

Is there any widely known general purpose library for standard C. I'm thinking of something like what Boost is for C++.

I found the C POSIX library... any other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good STL-like library for C.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540/good-stl-like-library-for-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[GLib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib), [GObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject), and [GTK+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gtk) (links to Wikipedia) are good places to start. ([GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/), [GObject](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/stable/), and [GTK](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/) are part of the [GTK+ Project](http://www.gtk.org/)).

For numerical functions and algebra, there are the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/), and implementations of [CLAPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) and CBLAS (GSL includes CBLAS).

Please see also [Wikipedia's list of numerical libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C_and_C.2B.2B). If you find more, consider contributing to the Wiki.

Comment: @Jefromi: thanks for the edits.
@Paul R: looks like the "related question link train" is as follows:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649649
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668501

Answer (score 3):

I have used [GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.6/) which provides almost every functionality of standard c libs.