# Data structures in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good STL-like library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540/good-stl-like-library-for-c)
>   [Are there any open source C libraries with common data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668501/are-there-any-open-source-c-libraries-with-common-data-structures)

Is there a "standard" library that C programmers use for frequently-used data structures (hash/tree-based sets/maps, heaps, etc.)? Or is there no single, well-known implementation?
(Something kind of like Boost for C++?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668501/are-there-any-open-source-c-libraries-with-common-data-structures

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540/good-stl-like-library-for-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206939/general-purpose-library-for-standard-c

Comment: @aix: Wow, didn't see those. Voting to close my post...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See GLib or APR (Apache Portable Runtime) library, they are the most well-known C libraries for data structures.

http://developer.gnome.org/glib

http://apr.apache.org

Comment: Just looking at GLib's website brings tears to my eyes (fonts aren't rendered correctly...), but APR looks pretty awesome -- seems to have [everything](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/0.9/group__APR.html). :) Will take a look at them, thanks! +1

Comment: GLib is much more complete, but APR is great too