# Where is the Apache Commons for C?

Tags: c, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good STL-like library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540/good-stl-like-library-for-c)
>   [Are there any open source C libraries with common data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668501/are-there-any-open-source-c-libraries-with-common-data-structures)

The Apache Commons project has always struck me as being the library of all things that were forgotten in the Java language. Nowadays I almost always include it by default as a dependency on all new projects.

Is there an equivalent of such an essential, must-have, have-it-all library for the C programming language? (And I really mean C---not C++).

Comment: Yeah, the C standard library.

Comment: Also, the only *"essential, must-have, have-it-all library"* for C++ I know is boost.

Comment: @Constantinius fine, so tell me where I can find a stack in the C standard library.

Comment: If you are looking for specific objects/functions/functionality you should state that in your question. If not your question *'ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form'*.

Comment: I guess C-programmers want to implement everything without extra libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the Gnome project's [GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/).

Comment: Which is a C library, but shouldn't be confused with glibc, the GNU C Library: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/).